# Native CodeIgniter function for fetching numbered arrays (PDO driver)?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, pdo

Standard way I get data from database as numbered array:

```
$query = $db_instance->prepare("SELECT some_field FROM table");
$query->execute();
$result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
```

Using CodeIgniter framework I learned about Query Helper Functions that help to get data like this:

```
$query = $db_instance->select('some_field');
$query = $db_instance->get('table');
$result = $query->result_array();
```

BUT the above script gives result which is an associative array, where first index is row number and second index is a field name.

Question: what code is to be added (and where in this second script) that output would be a numbered array instead an associative one (I assume that PDO::FETCH_NUM should be added in some function as parameter)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CodeIgniter doesn't have a method that does that, and IMO it wouldn't bring any benefit if it did.

If you really, really need numbered indexes just call `array_values()` on the associative array.

Comment: You're just not using it right ... you're doing `array_values($query->result_array())`, but that's a numeric array containing multiple associative ones - you'd want to use it on them.